# Fitting ARIMA+GARCH in R

Tags: r

I have a line of code in R:

```
garchFit(substitute(formula~arma(p,q)+garch(1,1),  
list(p=auto.arima(data[i:(i+T-1)])$arma[1],q=auto.arima(data[i:(i+T-1)])$arma[2])),  
data = data[i:(i+T-1)],trace=F)
```

which is fitted repeatedly in a "for" loop for different i but unfortunately produces an error at when i reaches 3613.

The code is designed to fit "best-fit" ARIMA model to the data ANF Garch(1,1) as there doesn't appear to be automatic "best fit" GARCH function in R unlike auto-arima.

The error is: `Error in arima(.series$x, order = c(u, 0, v), include.mean = include.mean) : non-stationary AR part from CSS.`.

In addition warning is produced: `In sqrt(diag(fit$cvar)) : NaNs produced.`

Any help on how to solve this issue much appreciated.

Comment: you should improve the code formatting within your question

Comment: @Christian MICHON done

Comment: I've edited for clarity and removed downvote. thx